Generate dynamic Types in typescript
Here is a class:
const COMMANDS = [
    "get-myanimelist-staff-urls",
    "get-myanimelist-anime-explicit-genres",
    "get-myanimelist-anime-genres",
    "get-myanimelist-anime-themes"
    ...
];

class Shiinobi {
    constructor() {
        COMMANDS.forEach((command) => {
            this[command.replaceAll("-", "_")] = async (...args: any[]) => {
                const id = args[0];
                return await this.#spawn({ command, id: id });
            };
        });
    }
    ...

and I use this Shiinobi class like:
const shiinobi = new Shiinobi();
const res = await shiinobi.get_myanimelist_staff_urls();

this is basically a valid code since constructor creates such methods.
but there is no type for such methods:
shiinobi.get_myanimelist_staff_urls()

this code shows ts-error
I tried with typescript custom Utility type, but no hope.
Edit:
here github repo code

Hi please can you provide all the error info.

Quick questions: 1. Do you need the dynamic methods to be accessible from inside the Shiinobi class? 2. What should the return type for your methods be?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! • Please [edit] to provide a [mre] with without references to undeclared things (like #spawn), but with all the information about the error message you received.

(see prev comment) • What do you expect to happen exactly? TS doesn't support truly dynamic keys on a class declaration; the closest you can get is an index signature. Are the keys supposed to be statically known from the contents of COMMANDS? If so, replaceAll() isn't strongly typed enough to transform string literal types. I could guess something like this is what you want, but it would be very helpful if you'd [edit] to clarify.

@DerekRoberts there were no error logs, its just typescript couldnt understand its types. I silenced it with // @ts-ignore

@moonstar-x 1. No i dont want to access it from inside (sorry i forgot to add full code of class). 2. It should be a promise like:Promise<any>

@jcalz yea sorry, just did :)

Hi, i just edited my question with a fix, well im wondering if there is any better way to do this. here is the ts playground of my current fix.

"there were no error logs, its just typescript couldnt understand its types." So then there were error logs when you ran tsc, or type errors in your IDE. Please [edit] to include those. See my comment about [mre] including #spawn, etc. According to the code you've presented here, your utility type shouldn't work because COMMANDS is of type string[] (maybe you want as const in there, but it's not here). I see you've got a link to your code in github, but that doesn't count as a [mre]. All relevant code should be in the question as plain text.

(pls see prev comment and respond) If you've found a fix (although it looks similar to other answers presented here) then it should be posted in an answer, not as an edit to the question. Asking for better ways to do things starts to be less appropriate for Stack Overflow and more appropriate for Code Review, so I'd suggest you don't do that here. Also note that nowhere in the question have you indicated that you want (id?: number) => Promise<any>, it's only in your edited solution. If you do post an answer, we still need a [mre] here that motivates it.

@jcalz hi, sorry i wasnt aware about Stack Overflow standards (it was my first time).
anyways, i posted an answer with example.
hope its good this time :)

I ended up with using a custom Utility which replaces - with _ and extended with Shiinobi interface.
Here is the changed code:
type Command = (typeof COMMANDS)[number];

type ReplaceHyphens<T extends string> = T extends `${infer P1}-${infer P2}`
    ? `${P1}_${ReplaceHyphens<P2>}`
    : T;

type ShiinobiProperties = {
    [K in Command as ReplaceHyphens<K>]: (id?: number) => Promise<any>;
};

interface Shiinobi extends ShiinobiProperties {}

And here a minimal reproduction example

You can first declare some types:
const COMMANDS = [
    "get-myanimelist-staff-urls",
    "get-myanimelist-anime-explicit-genres",
    "get-myanimelist-anime-genres",
    "get-myanimelist-anime-themes"
    // ...
] as const;

type COMMANDS_TYPE = typeof COMMANDS;

type ReplaceDashWithUnderscore<T extends string> =
  T extends `${infer P1}-${infer R1}` ? `${P1}_${ReplaceDashWithUnderscore<R1>}` :
  T extends `${infer P2}-${infer R2}` ? `${P2}_${ReplaceDashWithUnderscore<R2>}` :
  T extends `${infer P3}-${infer R3}` ? `${P3}_${ReplaceDashWithUnderscore<R3>}` :
  T extends `${infer P4}-${infer R4}` ? `${P4}_${ReplaceDashWithUnderscore<R4>}` :
  T extends `${infer P5}-${infer R5}` ? `${P5}_${ReplaceDashWithUnderscore<R5>}` :
  T;

type Underscore<T extends COMMANDS_TYPE> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? ReplaceDashWithUnderscore<T[K]> : never;
};

type ToObj<T extends Underscore<COMMANDS_TYPE>> = {
  // TODO Should Promise<void> be Promise<return type of spawn>
  [K in T[number]]: (id: string, ...args: any[]) => Promise<void>; 
};

The above allows you to define an object with the commands as methods in the right format:

Then, instead of using a class, you can use a factory for an object literal. This will be easier to deal with when using dynamic properties:
function shinobiFactory() {

  // private stuff
  const somethingPrivate: number = 0;

  interface SpawnConfig {
    command: typeof COMMANDS[number];
    id: string;
  }

  function spawn(config: SpawnConfig) {
    return somethingPrivate;
  }

  function someOtherMethod() {
    return somethingPrivate;
  }

  function underscore<T extends string>(s: T) {
    return s.split("-").join("_") as ReplaceDashWithUnderscore<T>;
  }

  const commandProps = COMMANDS.reduce(
    (prev, curr) => {
      const key = underscore(curr)
      const value = async (id: string, ...args: any[]) => {
        return await spawn({ command: curr, id: id });
      };
      const update = {
        ...prev,
        ...{
          [key]: value
        }
      };
      return update;
    },
    {}
  ) as ToObj<Underscore<COMMANDS_TYPE>>;

  // Return only what you want to be public
  return {
    ...commandProps,
    someOtherMethod
  }
  
}

Finally, you can invoke the method to create instances of your "class". As you can see both properties and arguments are correct:


Playground demo

hi, yes this is really close to what i needed (sorry i couldnt add full requirements). i managed to fix it with a custom utility like this, im pretty new to typescript can you check my edited question? thank you :)
